# Azure Default Database cleanage

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

Some weeks ago I've made an android prototype and deployed the services and databases to my azure free account. Today, for my dismay I've found out that all my data was cleaned.
I've searched a bit but didn't find any plausible reason for this event.

So my question is, Is there any way/reason that Azure cleans any data for free/premium accounts? If yes, can i retrieve it?

EDIT:
In case of a reboot by Azure servers, the data is kept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure doesn't do automatic cleaning. However if you deploy your database again I can quite easily see it being basically deleted and recreated.

I never redeploy an Azure db. If I need to make changes, I create a change script and connect to the db from local SSMS and run the script. A bit boring but it works.

And no: rebooting won't loose data either.

Comment: for the sake of curiosity, what are your 2 cents about this event?

Comment: but i didn't. when i did a deploy there wasn't any database

Comment: Hmm. I guess you must have done something. My Azure databases never get touched.

Comment: well at least there is no warm because it was all mocked data. I should make some backups though

Comment: OK. Sorry I couldn't help more. Try putting a trigger on one or two tables to record deletes in an audit table. That might show something in the future.....

Answer (score 1):

Azure is meant to store your data irrespective of your subscription type. If your trial period is completed azure will keep the data for few days and then it will drop a warning mail before deleting your data.If above is not the case then you should immediately contact [Azure support](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/options/). I hope they will be able to give you brief information about your account/data and will help you in recovering as well.